# SQL counting different column values

Tags: mysql, case

I have a table called spider_status which has a status_code and a locationid. I am retrieving all cities from region_select_city which I joined in the code below. Now I am trying to count all the unique values in status_code in the table spider_status grouping by cities.

```
SELECT region_select_city.name as stad , COUNT(spider_status.id) as spider_aantal,
CASE WHEN spider_status.status_code = 1 THEN COUNT(spider_status.status_code) ELSE 0  END as LIVE
FROM
spider_status
 JOIN 
location 
ON spider_status.location_id = location.id
 JOIN
location_select_addressid 
ON location.id = location_select_addressid.locationid
JOIN
location_address
ON location_select_addressid.addressid = location_address.id 
JOIN
region_select_city 
ON location_address.city_id = region_select_city.id
JOIN
spider_status_code
ON spider_status.status_code = spider_status_code.id 
WHERE spider_status.current = 1
GROUP BY region_select_city.name
```

Comment: simply say you have table spider_status  and you need to count unique attempts of status_code and group your values by cities am i right?

Comment: Yes! exactly. The cities are in another table named region_select_city

Comment: what is the name of field which indicate city in table spider_status

Comment: There is no indication. There is only a locationid, which is linked to location and location is linked to location_address which has a city_id that links to region_select_city.

Comment: Check this edits Rahul it should be okay for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the following code help you to solve the issue

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT s.status_code) 
FROM spider_status AS s 
JOIN location AS l
ON l.locationid = s.locationid
JOIN location_address AS loc_add
ON loca_add.locationid = loc_add.locationid
GROUP BY loc_add.city_id
```

Comment: I came up with this query, but the result should bring up 66 on a specific row but instead it results in 46.



`SELECT rsc.name, count(DISTINCT s.status_code) 
FROM spider_status AS s 
JOIN location AS l
ON l.id = s.location_id
JOIN location_select_addressid AS loca_add_id
ON loca_add_id.locationid = l.id
JOIN location_address AS loca_add
ON loca_add.id = loca_add_id.addressid
JOIN region_select_city AS rsc
ON loca_add.city_id = rsc.id
GROUP BY loca_add.city_id`

Comment: I think it should be done with cases, however I am unable to figure out how it should work. That's why I tried doing this

`CASE WHEN spider_status.status_code = 1 THEN COUNT(spider_status.status_code) ELSE 0  END as LIVE`

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the 2nd last line, should the AND be there?

Comment: please use comments to ask for more information or to pass hints.